# using only two-input NOR gates to implement the following function

Tags: boolean-algebra

> F(A,B,C,D)=(A⊕B)'(C⊕D)

```
=(AB'+A'B)'(CD'+C'D)
=(AB')'(A'B)'(CD'+C'D)
=(A'+B)(A+B')(CD'+C'D)
```

how to simplify further

Answer (score 1):

When rewriting a formula for implementation with NOR gates, we aim for a product-of-sums form, because then the translation is immediate.  In this case, the trick is to rewrite $(C \oplus D)$ as $(C+D)(C'+D')$ to obtain a product of sums (POS).

Once you have your POS, you get a two-level NOR-NOR circuit with one NOR for each clause of the POS and one NOR gate to combine the outputs of the first-level gates.  Of course, you also need four inverters, which you may consider one-input NOR gates.

Note that this procedure is the dual of the one that turns any sum of products into a two-level NAND-gate circuit.

In this case the second-level NOR gate would have four inputs, because there are four clauses in the product of sums.  If you can only use two-input gates, then you need to decompose the four-input NOR into three two-input NORs and two inverters.  If inverters are off limits, you can use two-input NOR gates with their inputs tied together instead.

If you want to go beyond two-level implementations things get significantly more interesting, but I bet you haven't gotten to that subject yet.

Answer (score 0):

We can write: $$(\bar A + B)(A + \bar B) = A \bar A + \bar A \bar B + AB + B\bar B = AB + \bar A \bar B $$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

18 Draw a logic diagram using only two-input NOR gates to implement the following function: 
F1A, B, C, D2 = (A { B)'(C { D)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Kindly use Mathjax.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)